# How to use Apache Flink write parquet file on HDFS by datetime partition?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

During ingest json data from kafka and save them as parquet files which be loaded into hive, I met the same issue mentioned in [Flink BucketingSink with Custom AvroParquetWriter create empty file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291889/flink-bucketingsink-with-custom-avroparquetwriter-create-empty-file)
. Does anyone know how to resolve it? Thank you. I used Apache Flink 1.4.0 + HDFS 2.7.3

Answer (score 2):

You can directly implement the `Writer` interface. It could look the following way:

```
import org.apache.flink.util.Preconditions;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroParquetWriter;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter;
import org.apache.parquet.hadoop.metadata.CompressionCodecName;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Parquet writer.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public class ParquetSinkWriter<T extends GenericRecord> implements Writer<T> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -975302556515811398L;

    private final CompressionCodecName compressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY;
    private final int pageSize = 64 * 1024;

    private final String schemaRepresentation;

    private transient Schema schema;
    private transient ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> writer;
    private transient Path path;

    private int position;

    public ParquetSinkWriter(String schemaRepresentation) {
        this.schemaRepresentation = Preconditions.checkNotNull(schemaRepresentation);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(FileSystem fs, Path path) throws IOException {
        this.position = 0;
        this.path = path;

        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }

        writer = createWriter();
    }

    @Override
    public long flush() throws IOException {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(writer);
        position += writer.getDataSize();
        writer.close();
        writer = createWriter();

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getPos() throws IOException {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(writer);
        return position + writer.getDataSize();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
            writer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(T element) throws IOException {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(writer);
        writer.write(element);
    }

    @Override
    public Writer<T> duplicate() {
        return new ParquetSinkWriter<>(schemaRepresentation);
    }

    private ParquetWriter<GenericRecord> createWriter() throws IOException {
        if (schema == null) {
            schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaRepresentation);
        }

        return AvroParquetWriter.<GenericRecord>builder(path)
            .withSchema(schema)
            .withDataModel(new GenericData())
            .withCompressionCodec(compressionCodecName)
            .withPageSize(pageSize)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I still met the following exception.
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: /wikipedia-edits-flink/partitionKey=2018-01-10--12-10/_part-5-0.in-progress for client 127.0.0.1 already exists ...
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2563) ...
 at flink.ParquetSinkWriter.createWriter(ParquetSinkWriter.java:98)
 at flink.ParquetSinkWriter.flush(ParquetSinkWriter.java:58)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.fs.bucketing.BucketingSink.snapshotState(BucketingSink.java:688)

Comment: Can it write parquet file without avro schema but through Apache Flink's DataFrame[T] type infer that?

Comment: I think you can get the `Schema` from the `AvroSerializer` which you can instantiate via the `AvroTypeInfo`.

Comment: @till reading this implementation and the bucketingSink implementation, is it correct to say that a hard failure will cause a complete loss of all the data currently in the parquetWriter cache? I guess this as not flushing data and not storing it in any state makes it impossible for the job to restore it...